# Serialization/arrays in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, serialization

I'm using this line of code to create a serialization of type string:

```
serialize( :name, String)
```

I cannot access strings using `:name[index]` in my code , I can only access chars of a string when doing this over the console. Why is this so ? Shouldn't this method provide me with what I'm looking for ? I've seen that in Rails 4 you can use actual `Array` datatypes but it does not let me store my strings inside saying that they expected an `Array` datatype and not a `String`. Shouldn't Rails arrays be just arrays ready to store any type of data ?

What I want to do is just having an array of strings. Is this even the correct way of doing it ?

Comment: You pass the data structure you want to store things in.  So if you want an array of strings you should have `serialize(:name, Array)` not `serialize(:name, String)`

Comment: Why does it report the error then ? It says that I need to pass an Array type and not String

Comment: I would guess that it doesn't support string and it defaults to Arrays.  Looking at is `Strings` don't respond to load so it wouldn't use a String http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html

Comment: How would you pass on a string to an array type ? By using some kind of to_a command or similar ?

Comment: `array << "My String"` or `array.push("My String")`

Comment: What's interesting is that I can do that in the console, but not over my form fields. I guess I have to make some kind of a filter to manipulate the data and turn it into an array from a string before saving ?

Comment: I didn't think you would, have you got a sample app somewhere?

Comment: It's nothing complicated, kind of just to learn about arrays here. So let's say that I have a serialized array like `serialize( :name, Array)` and in my form a simple line like so: `<% f.text_field :name %>`. How could I be able to use the `.push` method or `<<` in this context ?